# Mern Deployment with heroku is not working

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mern

**I'm trying to deploy the MERN app but it is neither giving me an error not finishing**
*My Folder Structure*

MERN_APP
------>upload-data //**this is client side react app**
------>index.js   //server-side code
------>pakage.json //and all files in same hierarchy

**Index.js (Server file)**

```
const express = require("express");
 const app = express();
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());
   //Importing routes
  const uploadRoute = require("./routes/uploadImage");
    const retrieveInfo = require("./routes/retrievePost");

    /*Routes section */
 //1. This route will upload data to the database
  app.use("/upload", uploadRoute);
  //2. This route will retrieve post from the database
  app.use("/retrieve", retrieveInfo);

    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      //   app.use(express.static("upload-data/build"));
    // }
   if (
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ||
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging"
     ) {
    app.use(express.static("upload-data/build"));
   app.get("*", (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/upload-data/build/index.html"));
     });
      }

    //Serverside code to run on a paticular port
   app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log("Unable to start backend server ", err);
   } else {
        console.log("Success fully started server on port ", PORT);
     }
     });
```

**Package.json file (Server side file)**

```
        {
         "name": "server",
           "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "\"Backend for uploading images and 
        videos\"",
        "main": "index.js",
         "scripts": {
         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
         "dev": "nodemon index.js",
         "build": "cd upload-data && npm start",
         "installClient": "cd upload-data && npm install",
          "heroku-postbuild": "npm run installClient && npm run 
      build",
         "start": "node index.js"
        },
       "author": "Kapil Chauhan",
       "license": "ISC"

       }
```

*I used proxy in client side but it is working file in local host, whenever I try to upload Don't get any error but my screen freezes after a particular point, I tired many ways but none of them are working, (I'm struct in this for many hours, Please help me)*

**UPLOADING process**

$ cd myapp
$ git init

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my first commit"
Then create (initialize) heroku app with:

$ heroku create YourAppName
Lastly add git remote:

$ heroku git:remote -a YourAppName
Now you can safely deploy your app with:

$ git push heroku main

**But still getting**
[Please look at the image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkA7q.png)
*Any Help will help me alot*

As you can see I am getting localhost:3000 option but not url,(also when I try to open localhost url it doesn't work).
I've build react application with (npm run build)

Comment: What does your heroku `Procfile` look like?

Comment: It is Procfile.txt in root folder of webapp, it has web: node index.js in it

Comment: _The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named Procfile without a file extension. For example, Procfile.txt is not valid._ from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Comment: You have two *warnings* but no *errors*. Also, Git is not involved in the messages you see here: it's just acting as a relay, sending Heroku's text back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through how you should deploy a node app with React frontend to heroku:

1. Create a `Procfile`, without any extension and add `web: node index.js` in it.
2. Add the Heroku git remote `heroku git:remote -a YourAppName`
3. Build the frontend, so `cd upload-data && npm run build`. This should create a `build` folder in the `upload-data` folder, which you should have correctly specified in your `index.js` static location.
4. `git add . && git commit -m "Your git message"`
5. `git push heroku main`

What I think is wrong right now is that your frontend application starts in development mode which it should not, because it should be your backend that starts with `node index.js`, which is specified in the Procfile, however, it should not be your `Procfile.txt`, only `Procfile`.

If you run into any problems with the frontend not being visible, then it's probably something wrong in your static express build. You may not event need the `app.get('*')` route.